# What is this growing outside my window?

Tags: mold, insect

Just noticed this on my window (external), it has been raining for a few days last week not sure if that's related.

Location: Melbourne, Australia.

- **What is it?**
- **How to deal with this?**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are mud-dauber wasps. They're good guys. They paralyze spiders, take them back to their nests, and lay eggs on the still-living spiders.

So if you don't like spiders around your place, leave the mud-daubers alone! Their homes are made of harmless mud, and they do not harm the underlying structure.

If you *really* despise them, you can simply scrape them off with a paint scraper. But they do no harm, so why not let them be?

Comment: That's one weird definition of 'good guys'...

Comment: Doing that will probably increase the number of flies around your home, with fewer spiders catching them.

Comment: Considering there are quite a few people with a fear of spiders (and of course regions where these can be actually dangerous), it'll depend on how afraid you are of them vs how much you dislike flies.

Comment: Considering that the 10 most deadly of _everything_ live in Australia, @Tetsujin, something that kills something that's deadly to humans is _generally_ classed as a "good guy". ;)

Comment: thanks, definitely afraid of spider specially in AUS :D

Comment: I'm actually a fan of most spiders, while realizing that most people don't share that mindset.